# How to reposition graphics in windows with no latency?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, windows-8, directx

I am trying to code custom cursor graphics for `Windows 8`. I will use it for an application which uses one or any number of `Wiimotes` to send touch input to `Windows`, which means I need to be able to display several `cursors`. I can not use the build in `cursor` for touch because they are very hard to see when it is viewed from a distance.

Currently I am using a separate transparent window for each cursor on which I draw the cursor graphics with `DirectX`, but for the actual re-positioning of the `cursor` I move the window to the current `cursor` position by using the `win32` methods `SendMessage` and `SetWindowPos`. This will result in a near zero latency for re-positioning, but it will use unreasonable amount of process time. Sometimes near `30%` when moving several cursors at the same time.

What I initially tried was drawing to a transparent window covering the whole screen. I've tried both a `WPF` window with re-positioning of shapes on a Canvas, and drawing directly to the `D3D` `DirectX` instance of `Desktop Window Manager` and re-position by changing transform `matrixes`. These will result in some very annoying milliseconds of latency.

How do I draw on screen, a `cursor` which will move with low latency and low `CPU`?

Comment: Can you not just use a single transparent window that overlays the entire screen?

Comment: Yes, that is what I did on my "other methods" but I do not know how I can reposition a graphic (preferrably anti-aliased and semi-transparent) without latency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using D3D / DirectDraw.

**Double buffering** is known to cause input lag, triple causes even more. And if you take **VSYNC** into account then the process would block for even as much as 20 ms.

That means you will have a 20ms gap between the input events.

Double/Tripple buffering aren't usually the problem 'cause VSYNC blocks for 2000% the time required to render the screen.

Because normally it takes 1-2 ms to render the screen but 17-24 ms waiting for VSYNC.

For example [c++]:
- Take a look <kbd>[here](http://www.drunkenhyena.com/cgi-bin/view_cpp_article.pl?chapter=2;article=10)</kbd> .

Comment: I am using D3D.
From what I see, maybe double buffering is my problem rather than my solution?
Quote from the first link "More buffers can smooth out your frame rate, but they can also cause input lag (delay between when the user hits a key and when he sees the results)." which is exactly what I am trying to avoid (input lag).

Comment: @Simphax I misread your question. I seriously thought you talked about frame-tearing when the cursor moved. Anyway, Double buffering does indeed cause input lag, triple causes even more.

Comment: @Simphax Check the answer again :).

Comment: Of course! Thank you!
The solution is setting ´PresentationInterval´ to ´D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE´ which will disable the Vsync and thus the input lag!